# How to allow dayname in input string when inputting a date?

Tags: ms-access, combobox

In our continuous form in Access we want to offer a combobox which will show 7 days with the dayname as part of the dropdown.

The combobox is bound to a date field. We can easily populate the combobox in the Form Load event to show the days in `ddd dd/MM/yy` format and existing dates are happily shown on the form like so:

[image]

However if you try and pick from the dropdown you get the error:
**The value you entered isn't valid for this field.**

Solutions involving an unbound combobox won't work as this is a continuous form.

It's kind of a detail, as the dayname isn't *absolutely* necessary, and the combo works fine without the dayname. However this is a heavy duty data entry form so optimising for the end user is important and having the daynames will assist him/her.

Comment: Have you considered a calendar table? They do not take much space and they are very useful.

Comment: @Remou we want to force user to pick from just those 7 days, so picklist seems more suitable to me than a calendar

Comment: You have converted the date to a string, so there is a datatype mismatch, consider two columns, one with a date ( hence the calendar suggestion ) and one with a formatted string.

Comment: @Remou two columns is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recreated the problem and the solution I came up with was to have a combo box where the row source has two columns and you hide the first column using `ColumnWidths` and the second column is the formatted date value.  So when you pick something in the combo box, the value is an unformulated date value which gives no issue.

Populate the combo like so:

```
Dim i As Integer
For i = 0 To 6
    Dim item As Date
    item = DateAdd("d", i, weekCommencingDate)
    cboTimeDate.AddItem item & ";" & Format(item, "ddd dd/MM/yy")
Next i
```

Comment: thanks @ashareef, i've edited in the code to help future visitors